# the method extracting a vertical column list in list of lists using recursive in Python

Tags: python, recursion

how can we Write a recursive function `column2list_rec(grid, n)`, where `grid` is a list of lists and `n` is an integer, that returns a list consisting of the element at position `n` of each row of grid.
assume that 0 ≤ n < len(r) for each row (i.e., element) of grid.

example:
the list:

```
[ [ 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd' ],
  [ 'ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh', 'ii', 'jj' ],
  [ 'kk', 'll', 'mm', 'nn' ] ]
```

the expect output is

```
column2list_rec(x,3)
return value: ['dd', 'hh', 'nn' ]
```

Comment: Smells like homework...

Comment: And why should this be done recursively? A simply recursive algorithm is enough.

Comment: `zip(*x)[3]` (python2) or `list(zip(*x))[3]` (python3) does what you need. I suppose the real challenge is to add some token recursion to that ;-)

Comment: Have you read [ask] and [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now i got:

```
if len(grid)>0: # not empty
    my_list = []
    item = grid[0][n]
    my_list.append(item)
    grid.pop(0)
    if len(grid) >0:
        return my_list + column2list_rec(grid, n)
    else:
        return my_list
else:
    return []
```

```